# jQuery/AJAX: Fetching the customer details when surname's are common

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

here is an issue that I am facing. As you can see in the question I need to get the customer details of a particular customer when their surnames are common.

Currently on selecting the customer's surname I get a popup with the list of all common surnames. While selecting a particular customer I get some completely different customer details.

I am using codeigniter. I will post my code of the mvc below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**VIEW (AJAX):-**

```
    $('.lname').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
        $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/agent/customer/customersByLastname'); ?>',
              data: {q:e.val},
              success: function(data){
                  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                  if(obj.length>1) {
                  var items = [];
                   $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
                       items.push("<li onclick='showSearch("+val.customer_id+")' value='"+val.customer_id+"'>"+val.name+" "+val.lname+"</li>");

                    });

                    $("#lnm").html(items);
                   $('#listmodal').modal('show');

                  }
              }
            }); 
});
function showSearch(id_cust) {

$.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/agent/customer/getCustomer'); ?>',
     type:'POST',
      data: {cid:id_cust},
      success: function(data){
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
           $('#customer_id').val(obj[0].customer_id);
          $('#select2-chosen-1').text(obj[0].customer_id);
          $('#select2-chosen-2').text(obj[0].name);
          $('#select2-chosen-5').text(obj[0].phone);
          $('#select2-chosen-4').text(obj[0].zip_code);
          $('#listmodal').modal('hide');

      }
    });

}
```

**CONTROLLER FUNCTIONS:-**

```
public function customersByLastname ()
{
$customers = $this->customer_m->getCustomerByLastname();

echo json_encode($customers);

}

public function getCustomer ()
{
$customer_id = $this->input->post('cid');
$this->load->model('customer_m');
$customer = $this->customer_m->getCustomerById($customer_id);
echo json_encode($customer);

}
```

**MODEL:-**

```
public function getCustomerByLastname(){
$search_term = $this->input->get('q');
$this->db->like('lname', $search_term);
$this->db->select('customer_id');
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->select('lname');
return $keywords = $this->customer_m->get();
}

public function getCustomerById($customer_id){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM naturescrm_customers WHERE id='".$customer_id."'");
return $query->result();
}
```

That is pretty much the code that I have done for this. If anything else is required. Kindly let me know. Thanks

Comment: is `customer_id` the same as `id` from `naturescrm_customers`?

Comment: `customer_id` has a prefix, where as the `id` is just an integer